# HIV and open reading frames

Tags: genetics, virology, translation, hiv

In [Wilk et al. 2001](http://jvi.asm.org/content/75/2/759.full) I saw that HIV has 3 open reading frames. In the [Watts et al. 2009](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v460/n7256/full/nature08237.html), I noticed they mentioned HIV has 9 open reading frames. I don't understand this very well.

e.g.

1. `[ATG] GAT GTA AGT`
2. `A[TG G]AT GTA AGT`
3. `AT[G GA]T GTA AGT`

Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Can you please link to the two articles you mention?

Comment: An open reading frame in this sense can, and in this case indeed it does, refer to transcribed regions.

Comment: Three: http://jvi.asm.org/content/75/2/759.full

Comment: Nine: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v460/n7256/full/nature08237.html